# Explicitly Import only one function from exported constant which stores multiple functions

Tags: ecmascript-6, import, javascript-import

I've a Constant like below stored in a file **helper.js**

```
export const Helper = {
  a() {
    return "This is just a string"
  },
  convertToSlug(str) {
    return str
      .toLowerCase()
      .replace(/[^\w ]+/g, "")
      .replace(/ +/g, "-")
  }
}
```

From this i want to import only convertToSlug function in another file like below

```
import { convertToSlug } from "helper.js"
```

How to do that? I tried the same but getting error

```
"export 'convertToSlug' was not found in '@/utils/helper'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want `import { convertToSlug } from "helper.js"` to work then you need to have an export named `convertToSlug`. Right now you've grouped everything inside `Helper` but there doesn't seem to be any reason for that.  It looks like most likely you'd want

```
export function a() {
  return "This is just a string"
}
export function convertToSlug(str) {
  return str
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/[^\w ]+/g, "")
    .replace(/ +/g, "-")
}
```

Comment: Hi @loganfsmyth,
Thank you for the answer. Yes I understand that if we export all functions as separate export we can import like what is expected. What I am trying is when we export all function into a single constant and import it'll come as an Object which has all functions as objects. So, isn't it possible to import it like Object destructing, that's what I wanted to know. Anyway thank you so much for the answer.

Comment: Then the answer is that you can't do that. You'd have to import `Helper` and then do `Helper.convertToSlug()` or do `const { convertToSlug } = Helper;` separately, which is why the pattern of exporting a bunch of helper functions in a single object is a bad idea. The ergonomics of it are not good and there is very little reason to do it.